# Resetting Period Dynamic Array Formula

Tags: arrays, excel, dynamic, forecast, sumproduct

I am trying to forecast the impact of monthly maturing balances for 12 consecutive months. The impact in each month = monthly balance * 1/12 * 1%. The next month, this maturing balance impact =  monthly balance * 2/12 * 1%, and so on until the final and twelfth month (where impact = monthly balance * 12/12 * 1%).

In each consecutive month, the balance multiplier should start again at 1/12 and work down to 12/12 (though balances in month 2 will begin at 1/12 and only work up to 11/12, as this forecast is limited to 12 months in total).

I appreciate any and all assistance guys!

Thank you,
Matt

[Here is the data table with my attempt at a formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDvLJ.png)

[Here is the formula dragged right and down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WerKR.png)

The issue is that now the formula in X14 has a multiplier of 2/12 (instead of 1/12).

[This would be the correct reference in the formula for X14, that has a multiplier of 1/12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyXYa.png)

[Intention is to aggregate the balances in each consecutive forecast month in column AI, and then sum these monthly forecast balances into a grand total in AI25](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZAph.png)

I have attempted using less space to write a sumproduct formula to encompass all the cells but I can never seem to get it over the line.

Comment: Your screenshots would have been much easier to follow if you had also included the Excel's row numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the second `$V13` in the formula for cell `W13` to `(1+$V13-W$10)` so that the formula now reads:

`=IF(W$10>$V13,0,W$11*(1+$V13-W$10)/12*1%)`

and copy to range `W13:AH24`.

This will now calculate 1/12 of 1% of the monthly balance (in row 11) for an element on the "leading diagonal" of `W13:AH24` with 2/12 in the cell below, 3/12 in the cell below that, etc.

Stripping the out the monthly balance, division by 12 and multiplication by 1% perhaps provides a clear view as to how this substitution works...

[image: Simplification to show effect of substitution]

Presumably, what you are wanting to do with your use of `SUMPRODUCT` is to calculate the grand total in cell `AI25`. It is not clear (to me at least) why you would want to do this (other than as an intellectual exercise) but the values shown in the picture above do provide a clue as to how to go about this.

Your `SUMPRODUCT` should have the balances in `W11:AH11` as one of its arguments, since each non-zero cell in `W13:AH24` is obtained by multiplication using the balance in row 11 of its same column as one of the multiplicands.

Looking at the table above `W11` should be multiplied 1+2+...+12 (and then divided by 12 and multiplied by 1%). Similarly, `X11` should be multiplied 1+2+...+11 (and, again, then divided by 12 and multiplied by 1%).

Stripping out the "divided by 12 and multiplied by 1%" (as these can be done outside the `SUMPRODUCT`) then the things to concentrate on are the series of:
1+2+...+12
1+2+...+11
etc

As any school student of mathematics probably knows 1+2+...+n is equal to n*(n+1)/2. It can also be noted that the value of n as 12 for column `W` is provided by  `13-W10`, and similarly those for columns `X`, `Y`, etc by `13-X10`, `13-Y10`, etc.

Putting this all together then a suitable formula involving use of `SUMPRODUCT` for cell `AI25` should be:

`=SUMPRODUCT((13-W10:AH10)*(14-W10:AH10)/2,W11:AH11)/12*1%`

### Addition

This addition addresses whether it is possible to produce similar formulae for the row totals in the range `AI13:AI24`.

Again, looking at the picture above and taking spreadsheet row 18 as an example, the requirement is to multiply `W11` by 6, `X11` by 5, ... , `AB11` by 1 and to sum the resulting products, which again suggests the use of `SUMPRODUCT`.

The required multipliers of 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 and 1 are obtained by subtracting the month numbers in `W10:AB10` from 7, which is conveniently provided as `1+V18`.

However, there is a complication. The length of the arrays forming the arguments of the `SUMPRODUCT` differs for each spreadsheet row. For spreadsheet row 18 the arrays should each contain 6 elements, but for row 17 it is 5 elements, whilst for row 19 it is 7 elements. Messy, but not impossible to deal with.

An alternative is to make each array 12 elements long but to make the multiplying integer 0 for the "unwanted" products. So, again in terms of row 18, cells `AC11` to `AH11` are each multiplied by 0. Now the twelve products involving `W11` to `AH11` can be summed to get the required total for cell `AI18`.

A suitable array expression for delivering the required 12 multipliers for row 18 is:
`(1+V18-W$10:AH$10)*(V18>=W$10:AH$10)`
and, as a result, the appropriate formula for cell `AI18` is

`=SUMPRODUCT((1+V18-W$10:AH$10)*(V18>=W$10:AH$10),W$11:AH$11)/12*1%`

and this formula can be copied to the range `AI13:AI24`.

### A challenge

The `SUMPRODUCT`'s for both the grand total and the row totals utilise only the ranges `W10:AH10` (containing the values 1-12 as a row), `W11:AH11` (containing the 12 monthly balances) and `V13:V24` (again containing the values 1-12, but this time as a column).

It is fairly straightforward to redesign the calculations to occupy just 3 columns - the first containing 1-12, the second containing the monthly balances and the third containing the subtotals currently in `AI13:AI24`. The challenge is not to do this but to justify doing this in terms of transparency and explaining how the calculations work.

Comment: Brilliant mate, thanks for the walkthrough/logic as well, very much appreciated. For the individual line sum formulas in AI13:AI24, is there a similar way to calculate these via a sumproduct?

Comment: @Matthew, I have added a section to my answer dealing with your individual line subtotals. I've also left you a challenge.